# Term/expression to describe a user's license (account) is allowed to be used?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I have a software that manages user accounts at a given service.

The administrator creates the account, the user validates e-mail and other data and then the account is considered to be valid/good for use.

I have a list/table that lists all accounts and I want a term/expression to fill a column of my table describing the situation of an account if it passed all the requirements.

For now, we are using:

> License Released

But this seems wrong to me, it looks as if the word ***Released*** tells me the license was deactivated, removed from the system. Preferably, I would like a adjective instead of `Released` that could perfectly describe the situation that it is now free for use and activated.

> License ______?

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Valid license" or "license validated".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[enabled](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/enable)**

> 1. **to give someone the ability** or opportunity **to do something**
> 2. **to make a computer or piece of equipment available for use by the user**

Answer (score 1):

Consider

- License ***[Approved](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/approve?q=approved)***

  > Officially agree to or accept as satisfactory

or

- License ***[Authorized](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/authorized)***

  > Having official permission or approval

[Reference : Oxford Dictionaries Online]